# ClojureScript: parsing a Transit response

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, transit

I started learning ClojureScript this week and I stuck parsing a Transit response, I have this function:

```
(defn handler [response]
   (let [comment (:comment response)
         created_at (:created_at response)
         last_name (:last_name response)
         _ (.log js/console (str ">>> COMMENT >>>>> " comment))
        comments_div (.getElementById js/document "comments")]
      (.append comments_div comment)
      (.log js/console (str "Handler response: " response))))
```

And the console shows:

[image]

So, "response" looks fine but I can't get the content from the "response" map (I think is a map) using:

```
 comment (:comment response) or comment (get response :comment)
```

The headers say that the response is an "application/transit+json" kind. I tried:

```
     (ns blog.core
        (:require [cognitect.transit :as t])) 

       (def r (t/reader :json))

      let [parsed (t/read r response).... <--- inside the let block
```

but no luck so far. Need I to parse the var "response"?

Comment: If the response is just a string, `:comment` will return `nil`, which won't show up in a string. Try `(type response)` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
 (ns blog.core
   (:require [domina :as dom]
        [ajax.core :refer [GET POST DELETE]]
        [cognitect.transit :as t]
        [bide.core :as r]))

(def r (t/reader :json))

(defn handler [response]
  (let [parsed (t/read r response)
        _  (.log js/console (str ">>> PARSED >>>>> " (type parsed) ">>>>" parsed))
    comment      (get parsed "comment")
    .... rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not working like a map, it probably is a string. Try checking the type of response. with

```
(println (type response))
```

If it is a string then :

```
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))
  (console.log ((json/read-str response) :comment))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you put me in the right track. Unfortunately,  clojure.data.json is exclusively for Clojure and won't work inside ClojureScript. However: "[cognitect.transit :as t]" do the trick.

Comment: Ohh thanks I didnt actually look at the API, just typed from the top of my head.